# Using methods in array list from TUI class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to access an (add) method in my arrayList class from a TUI class, which will add a user to my arrayList.

This is my TUI class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BorrowerTUI
{

private BorrowerList borrowerList;
private Scanner myScanner;


public BorrowerTUI()
{
    myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    BorrowerList borrowerList = new BorrowerList();
}

public void menu()
{
int command = -1;
while (command != 0)
{   
    displayMenu();
    command = getCommand();
    execute (command);
}
}



private void displayMenu()
{
System.out.println( "Options are" );
System.out.println( "Enter 1" );
System.out.println( "Enter 2" );
System.out.println( "Enter 3" );
System.out.println( "Enter 4" );

}

private void execute( int command)
{
if ( command == 1)
    addBorrower();
else
if ( command == 2 )
    getNumberOfBorrowers();
else
if ( command == 3)
    quitCommand();
else
if ( command == 4)
    quitCommand();
else
if ( command == 5)
    quitCommand();
else
    System.out.println("Unknown Command");
}


private int getCommand()
{
    System.out.print ("Enter command: ");
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    myScanner.nextLine(); 
    return command;
}

public void getNumberOfBorrowers()
{
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("We have" + borrowerList.getNumberOfBorrowers() + "borrowers");
}

public void quitCommand()
{
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Application Closing");
    System.exit(0);
}


public void addBorrower()
{
    Borrower borrower = new Borrower();
    borrowerList.addBorrower(borrower);
}
}
```

This is my array list class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BorrowerList
{
   private ArrayList<Borrower> borrowers;    


   public BorrowerList()
   {
       borrowers = new ArrayList<Borrower>();
    }

   public void addBorrower(Borrower borrower)
   {
       borrowers.add(borrower);
   }

   public int getNumberOfBorrowers()
   {
       return borrowers.size();
   }

   public boolean getBorrower(String libraryNumber)
   {
       for(Borrower borrower : borrowers)

       borrower.getLibraryNumber();
       return true;
   }

   public void getBorrower(int borrowerEntry)
   {
       if (borrowerEntry < 0)
       {
           System.out.println("Negative entry: " + borrowerEntry);
       }
       else if (borrowerEntry < getNumberOfBorrowers())
       { 
           Borrower borrower = borrowers.get(borrowerEntry);
           borrower.printBorrowerDetails();
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("No such entry: " + borrowerEntry);
       }
   }

   public void getAllBorrowers()
   {
        for(Borrower borrower : borrowers)
        {
            borrower.printBorrowerDetails();
            System.out.println();
        }
   }

   public void removeBorrower(int borrowerEntry)
   {
        if(borrowerEntry < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
        else if(borrowerEntry < getNumberOfBorrowers())
        {
            borrowers.remove(borrowerEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No such entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
   }

   public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
   {
        int index = 0;
        for (Borrower borrower: borrowers)
        {
            if (libraryNumber.equals(borrower.getLibraryNumber()))
            {
                borrowers.remove(index);
                return true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return false;
   }


   public int search(String libraryNumber)
   {
       int index = 0;
       for (Borrower borrower : borrowers)
       {
           if (libraryNumber.equals(borrower.getLibraryNumber()))
           {
               return index;
           }
           else
           {
               index++;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }    
}
```

But for some reason when I try to link this method in my TUI class using the code at the top, it is returning the error: ") expected after 'User'"

Can somebody help, thanks.

Comment: Remove the type from the method call.

Comment: Is it a compile error or a runtime exception? what is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: The line that the error occurs is on the 'userList.adduser(User user)', it's a compile error and apparently the error is after the first 'User' where it says a ')' is expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning an error because the method addUser is expecting a User object as input. In your call of the function, you gave it the User type as if you were declaring a method. Try passing in just a user object like so:

```
public void addUser()
{
    User user = new User();
    userList.addUser(user);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested but I am now getting an error 'no suitable constructor found for Borrower(no arguments)'

Comment: That error is being thrown because there is no constructor for your User object that takes no arguments. What does the User class that you're using look like? Do you have a User object that is initialized in the TUI class?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to copy the class as it's saying it's too long. I'll amend my original post and add the full code.

Comment: I've amended my original post including the code for both of my classes, the names are actually borrower not user I was just using 'user' as a metaphorical example earlier, above are the actual names used in my class. Thanks a lot

Comment: Where exactly in the amended code are you getting the error?